# Strawberry Perl v5.30.0 not able to install Tcl (Windows 10)

Tags: perl, tcl, cpan, strawberry-perl, tclsh

I downloaded and installed strawberry-perl-5.30.0.1-64bit.msi from [strawberryperl.com](http://strawberryperl.com/) on my Windows 10 and tried to install Tcl module using cpan, but it fails for missing tclsh. What could be the problem?

```
C:\Strawberry>cpan Tcl
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.217)
Database was generated on Thu, 24 Oct 2019 12:40:15 GMT
Running install for module 'Tcl'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.086)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\V\VK\VKON\Tcl-1.27.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.32)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.78)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20190522)
Configuring V/VK/VKON/Tcl-1.27.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
'tclsh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error starting tclsh: $?=256; $!=
No 'Makefile' created  VKON/Tcl-1.27.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Tcl'.

C:\Strawberry>dir C:\Strawberry\cpan\build\Tcl-1.27-0
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is BCC0-703E

 Directory of C:\Strawberry\cpan\build\Tcl-1.27-0

25.10.2019  13.05    <DIR>          .
25.10.2019  13.05    <DIR>          ..
14.07.2018  11.00             5 207 Changes
22.08.2018  11.21            10 139 Makefile.PL
22.08.2018  11.45             1 723 MANIFEST
22.08.2018  11.45             1 140 META.json
22.08.2018  11.44               617 META.yml
14.07.2018  20.26             1 246 README
25.10.2019  13.05    <DIR>          t
25.10.2019  13.05    <DIR>          tcl-core
22.08.2018  11.43            43 540 Tcl.pm
22.08.2018  10.57            46 049 Tcl.xs
16.06.2018  15.18               439 tclcfg.tcl
16.06.2018  15.18                48 typemap
              10 File(s)        110 148 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  316 953 681 920 bytes free
```

Comment: Clearly there's a dependency. Go install Tcl: https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/

Answer (score 0):

You can build the missing dependency `tclsh` by downloading the source distribution from https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8420-src.zip. To compile the source you need a C compiler. I tried the community edition of visual studio:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

- Click download community edition..
- Then choose what to install
- Then click "Install"

After installation, go to menu "Tools->Command Line->Developer Command Prompt" and run

```
nmake -f makefile.vc
```

from the `win` sub folder of the extracted Tcl source distribution (on my computer it was located at `C:\Users\Bruker\tcl\tcl8.4.20\win`)

The above `nmake` command creates a new folder `Release_VC13` with an executable file `tclsh84.exe`. Note that the name of the executable is not `tclsh.exe`.

Now add the folder of the executable to the system `PATH` environment variable:
`C:\Users\Bruker\tcl\tcl8.4.20\win\Release_VC13`, then close the command prompt and reopen again to refresh the path settings.

Try type `tclsh84`, and you should get a tcl shell command prompt with a leading `%` prompt. Then type `exit` to exit the tcl shell.

The next problem is to install the `Tcl` module using Strawberry perl. Trying first to run:

```
> cpan Tcl
[...]
'tclsh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error starting tclsh: $?=256; $!=
No 'Makefile' created  VKON/Tcl-1.27.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Tcl'.
```

The problem is that the executable is not called `tclsh` but `tclsh84` (see above).

The next thing I did was to download the source distribution for the `Tcl` module:

```
> cpan -g Tcl
```

Then extracted the downloaded file `Tcl-1.27.tar.gz` and changed to the source distribution directory. By inspecting the `Makefile.PL` I found that the `Makefile.PL` took a command line argument `--tclsh` that gave the name of the tcl shell command. So I tried:

```
> perl Makefile.PL --tclsh=tclsh84
```

and this worked fine now. Then I tried to compile with `gmake` (which comes with the Strawberry Perl distribution):

```
> gmake
```

This also worked, but running `gmake test` failed, and also installing and testing the module:

```
> gmake install  
> perl -MTcl -e1
failed dlopen(C:/Users/Bruker/tcl/tcl8.4.20/win/Release_VC13/tcl84.dll,...);
failed dlopen(./tcl84.dll,...);
failed dlopen(tcl84.dll,...);
trying dlopen(tcl89.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl88.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl87.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl86.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl85.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl84.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl83.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl82.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl81.dll,...)
trying dlopen(tcl80.dll,...)
failed all posible tcl vers 8.x from 9 down to 0 at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 111.
Failed to load Tcl dll! at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 111.
Unable to initialize Tcl at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 111.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

I plan to come back to this problem later and investigate further.