# Tcl call in perl script

Tags: perl, tclsh

I am executing a Perl script that makes use of `use Tcl;`. This currently invokes tcl8.4.

When I check my lib path, tcl8.5 is also found. I want `use Tcl;` to use tcl8.5 instead of tcl8.4. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Please provide any information about your code and system.

Comment: See also [Strawberry Perl v5.30.0 not able to install Tcl (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58556585/2173773)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [the distro's `Makefile.PL`](https://metacpan.org/source/VKON/Tcl-1.27/Makefile.PL), I believe it uses a `tclshX.Y` found when the module is installed.

If a newer version 8.5 of Tcl has been installed since you installed the module, you could try to reinstall the module.

```sh
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/V/VK/VKON/Tcl-1.27.tar.gz
tar xvzf Tcl-1.27.tar.gz
cd Tcl-1.27
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
```

If that isn't sufficient, this module's `Makefile.PL` accepts arguments that help locate the correct `tclsh`. As mentioned in [the distro's `README` file](https://metacpan.org/source/VKON/Tcl-1.27/README), you can see the accepted options using the following:

```sh
perl Makefile.PL --help
```

Comment: make test
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Tcl/Tcl.so
gcc  -shared -O2 Tcl.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Tcl/Tcl.so    \
   -L/homes/naveenmathil/TCl_module/Tcl-1.27/tcl-core/linux-i686 -ltclstub8.4   \

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /homes/naveenmathil/TCl_module/Tcl-1.27/tcl-core/linux-i686/libtclstub8.4.a when searching for -ltclstub8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltclstub8.4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'blib/arch/auto/Tcl/Tcl.so' failed
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Tcl/Tcl.so] Error 1

Comment: 1) That's still trying to use 8.4. 2) This would be a different problem that should get a new question. I don't know the answer.